# Prove that the forward image of $V$ under $f^{-1}$ is the same set as the inverse image of $V$ under $f$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, inverse-function

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a bijective function, and let $f^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ be its inverse. Let $V$ be any subset of $Y$. Prove that the forward image of $V$ under $f^{-1}$ is the same set as the inverse image of $V$ under $f$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

By definition, the inverse image of $V$ under $f$ is given by the set
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(V) = \{x\in X \mid f(x)\in V\}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the forward image of $V$ under $f^{-1}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(V) = \{f^{-1}(y)\in X\mid y \in V\}
\end{align*}

Thus we have to prove that $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\} = \{f^{-1}(y)\in X\mid y\in V\}$.

> Let us consider the inclusion $(\subseteq)$ first.

If $a\in\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\}$, then $a\in X$ and $f(a) = v \in V\subseteq Y$.

Since $f$ is bijective, $a = f^{-1}(v)\in X$.

Hence $a\in\{f^{-1}(y)\in X\mid y\in V\}$.

> Conversely, let us prove the inclusion $(\supseteq)$.

If $a\in\{f^{-1}(y)\in X\mid y\in V\}$, $a = f^{-1}(v)\in X$ and $v\in V$.

Once again, since $f$ is bijective, we conclude that $v = f(a)\in V\subseteq Y$.

Thus $a\in\{x\in X \mid f(x)\in V\}$.

Could someone double-check my reasoning?

Comment: It looks correct.